# How to attach files with space in filename when sending email

Tags: python, email, email-attachments, mime

I am developing a Python application to send email. I follow [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/send-mail-attachment-gmail-account-using-python/) and attach with this code:

```
import smtplib 
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart 
from email.mime.text import MIMEText 
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase 
from email import encoders 

def prepare_attachment(filepath):
    filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
    attachment = open(filepath, "rb")

    # instance of MIMEBase and named as p 
    p = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')

    # To change the payload into encoded form.
    p.set_payload((attachment).read())

    # encode into base64 
    encoders.encode_base64(p)

    p.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

    return p


class Sender(object):

    # other code...

    def send(self):
        msg = MIMEMultipart() 

        # other code...

        # open the file to be sent
        for attachment in self.attachments:

            p = prepare_attachment(attachment)
            
            # attach the instance 'p' to instance 'msg' 
            msg.attach(p)

        # rest of code...
```

The code runs and send the email. When the user adds an attachment, such as `my attachment.pdf`, the receiver sees `my` as the name of the attachment and their client does not show a preview of the attachment.

When I replace spaces in the filename with `%20`, the receiver sees a preview of the file but also sees `%20` in the filename.

How can I attach files with spaces in the filename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the filename in quotes:

```
p.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % filename)
```